# Polling vs hidden iFrame for Ajax history

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, browser, browser-history

**Background**

Detection of hash change in the URL and fixing the forward/back button are two requirements for libraries that deal with Ajax history. There's two schools of thought for implementing these libraries. You can have a poller constantly check the URL (bad browsers don't have the onHashChange event). Or you can use a hidden iFrame to add points in your browser history. One may think the hidden iFrame is better than polling, but the hidden iFrame does not update the outer browser's URL. So if a user wanted to share her current state in the web application, she would always be sharing her initial state.

**Question**

Is there any technique for Ajax history that both doesn't require polling and also updates the main browser's URL?

Comment: What problem does the polling solve? Are you trying to solve the case where a user manually appends a hash identifier onto the current URL? How often is that going to happen?

Comment: Here's an example: The user clicks a button. The onClick handler updates the hash values. The user clicks the back button. Now the hash values have been reverted. IE6/7 don't have onHashChange, so you need to poll window.location for changes when the user hits forward/back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a combination of the two techniques? change the url, as well as use the iframe. ignore hashChanged (on good browsers), and just parse the hash code on dom:ready

Comment: Do you know a library that does this (I use Prototype)? It's a nightmare dealing with the inconsistencies of Safari vs FF vs IE cross product with dynamic vs static iFrames.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your comments from the original question, I would recommend using the iframes method for IE and polling for other browsers.

Check out [Real Simple History](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) if you are looking for a library that handles this specifically and you want a basis to help roll your own.

If you are just looking for the functionality of keeping your page's state in an Ajax UI, dojo supports this with the [dojo.hash()](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/hash) shim.  This method creates the [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.onhashchange) event for browsers that do not support it and manages the state of your back button.  It uses a mix of polling and iframes depending on the browser (iFrames are used specifically in IE versions < 8).